# One canvas to interact, three to display

Tags: javascript, canvas, box2d

i'm creating a browser game which is meant to be played as a hologram.
The screen should be displaying something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y60mfBvXCj8

Therefore i thought i have to create 4 canvas (no problem), but three of them should only display whats happening on the first.
I've tried to let it draw an Image of the canvas and let it display to the other canvas.

Any help would be appreciated!

The game is created with Box2D.

edit:

i want the space ship to be drawn in every canvas, but only controlled in one.

my code: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=68837773176112789787

the problem is, that its only displaying on one canvas!

what i've put in the HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"  width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3"  width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas4"  width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

what is meant to print it to the others:

JS

```
var sourceCtx, destinationCtx, imageData;

//get the context of each canvas
sourceCtx = canvas2.getContext('2d');
canvas2Ctx = canvas3.getContext('2d');

//copy the data
imageData = sourceCtx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas2.width - 1, canvas2.height - 1);

//apply the image data
canvas3Ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

//done
```

Comment: It's good to know what you wish to achieve but what is your question and where is the relevant source code to whatever your question is?

Comment: i want the space ship to be drawn in every canvas, but only controlled in one.
thanks for your help.
code: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=68837773176112789787

Comment: i also tried this:
https://jsperf.com/copying-a-canvas-element
without any effect

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve but what problem(s) are you having with your current attempt? This isn't a free writing service where you explain what you want and others write it for you. StackOverFlow is for people with an existing problem with source code. Please take a look at [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the problem is, that its only displaying on one canvas! also i linked you the whole code

Comment: Why not include the relevant source code to your question rather than leaving the only option of seeing the source code by downloading a file you have uploaded... I'm here to help but I am not downloading unknown files people upload. This site allows you to display source code and run snippets so please use the resources provided if you want help.

Comment: okay, i've edited my question. if you know any site that allows you to upload and display my file with multiple JS, let me know. thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Holographic pyramid display

How to render for a pyramid reflecting display.

To do this use a single display canvas in the HTML and a canvas stored in memory for rendering.

#### Mirrored render canvas

The rendering canvas is clipped to a triangle to prevent pixels overlapping and the transform is mirrored so that the final effect is correctly seen. Eg text is back to front.

The offscreen rendering canvas is then rendered to the display canvas, starting at the top and making a total of 4 copies each rotated 90deg.

The rendering canvas width will be the minimum of the display width or height and half that for the height in order to fit the display.

#### Needs fullscreen mode

For the FX to work you will need to enter fullscreen mode. I have not included how this is done but I am sure there is a QA on stackoverflow that will step you through the process.

#### Dead zone

At the center of the display is a area on which the pyramid will rest (I call it the dead zone) As many of these displays are homemade the size of the dead zone will vary. In the very first line of the demo below is a constant `deadZoneSize` that will set the dead zone size. It is currently set at 0.1 which is 10% of the view size. You may need to adjust this value to suit your particular reflecting display.

#### Example code

The code example is full of comments in the relevant parts. It will create and setup the display canvas and render canvas. Create the clip area and set up the mirrored rendering transform, so you can render as normal. A `mainLoop` function will call a function called `renderContent` with the first argument as being the context of the render canvas. Just render your content as normal (use `size` and `hSize` for the width and height of the visible render area (maybe I should have used a better name))

The demo includes an example rendering just for the fun of it, that is all at the bottom and has minimum comments as not really relevant to the question.

```js
const deadZoneSize = 0.1; // As fraction of fitted box size

// for FX em and em4 are just custom unit size and 1/4 size
var em,em4;
// to fit all four views use the min width or height
var size = Math.min(innerWidth,innerHeight);
// half size
var hSize = size / 2 | 0;
// there is a small area where nothing should be displayed.
// This will depend on the pyrimide being used.
var deadZone = size * 0.1 | 0; // about 10% of view area

// Display canvas d for display
const dCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// Render canvas
const rCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// get rendering context for both
const dCtx = dCanvas.getContext("2d");
const rCtx = rCanvas.getContext("2d");

// Set the display canvas to fill the page
Object.assign(dCanvas.style,{
    position : "absolute",
    zIndex : 10, // place above 
    top : "0px",
    left : "0px",
    background : "black",
})

// add the display canvas to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(dCanvas);


//Size function resizes canvases when needed
function resize(){
    startTime = undefined;
    size = Math.min(innerWidth,innerHeight);
    hSize = size / 2 | 0;
    deadZone = size * deadZoneSize | 0; // about 10% of view area
    dCanvas.width = innerWidth;
    dCanvas.height = innerHeight;
    rCanvas.width = size; 
    rCanvas.height = hSize;  // half height
    em = size * 0.1 | 0; // define our own unit size
    em4 = Math.max(1,em * 0.25 | 0); // define quarter unit size min of 1    
}

// To ensure pixels do not stray outside the view area and overlap use a clip on the render canvas
// ctx the context to appy the clip path to
function defineClip(ctx){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(size,0);
    ctx.lineTo(hSize + deadZone, hSize - deadZone);
    ctx.lineTo(hSize - deadZone, hSize - deadZone);
    ctx.clip();
    
    // The rendering is mirrored from the holo pyramid
    // to avoid seeing text mirrored you need to mirror the
    // rendering transform
    
    ctx.setTransform(-1,0,0,1,size,0); // x axis from right to left, origin at top right  
}

// Copying the rendered canvas to the display canvas
// ctx is the display canvas context
// image is the rendered canvas
function display(ctx,image) {
    // for each face of the pyramid render a view
    // Each image is just rotated 90 deg
    
    // first clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    
    // top
    // use the center of the display canvas as the origin
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,ctx.canvas.width / 2 | 0, ctx.canvas.height / 2 | 0);
    // draw the image
    ctx.drawImage(image,-hSize,-hSize);

    // Right
    ctx.transform(0,1,-1,0,0,0);  // rotate 90 deg. This is better than ctx.rotate as it can have slight
                                  // problems due to floating point errors if not done correctly
    ctx.drawImage(image,-hSize,-hSize);
    // bottom
    ctx.transform(0,1,-1,0,0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-hSize,-hSize);
    // left
    ctx.transform(0,1,-1,0,0,0);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-hSize,-hSize);
    
    // restore the default transform;
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

}



// the main render loop 
var globalTime;
var startTime;
function mainLoop(time){
    // check canvas size. If not matching page then resize
    if(dCanvas.width !== innerWidth || dCanvas.height !== innerHeight) {
        resize();
    }
    if(startTime === undefined){ startTime = time }
    globalTime = time - startTime;
    
    // clear the render canvas ready for next render
    rCtx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // reset transform
    rCtx.globalAlpha = 1;           // reset alpha
    rCtx.clearRect(0,0,size,hSize);
    
    // save the context state so that the clip can be removed
    rCtx.save();   
    defineClip(rCtx); // set the clip
    renderContent(rCtx); // call the rendering function

    // restore the context state which removes the clip
    rCtx.restore();
    
    // rendering is ready for display so render the holo view
    // on to the display canvas's context
    display(dCtx, rCanvas);


    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);




//=====================================================================================================
// The following is just something interesting to display and is not directly related to the answer
//=====================================================================================================


// The main rendering function 
// This is where you render your content. It can be anything from a game to just plain old text
// You can even use a video element and display a video.
// The rendering context is already set up to correctly mirror the content so just render everything as normal

const randG  = (min, max , p = 2) => (max + min) / 2 + (Math.pow(Math.random(), p) * (max - min) * 0.5) * (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1);

const bootUp = ["Power On",1,1000,"Sub system test",0.5, 3000, "Calibrating scanner",0.5, 6000, "Welcome",1,8000];
function noisyText(ctx){
    var textTime = globalTime / 8000; // 8 second boot up
    if(screenFlashDone){
        if(globalTime > screenFlashes[0]) { // play screen flash seq
            screenFlashes.shift();
            screenFlash(ctx,true,screenFlashes.shift(),screenFlashes.shift());
        }
    }else{
         screenFlash(ctx);
    }
    
    ctx.font = ((bootUp[1] * em) | 0) + "px monospace";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "center";
    var tx = randG(-em4 * 4, em4 * 4, 64);  // G for kind of a bit like gausian. Last num controls distrubution
    var ty = randG(-em4 * 4, em4 * 4, 64);
    var xx = size / 2 + tx;
    var yy = em * 2 + ty;
    ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${randG(160,250,32)|0},100%,50%)`;
    if(bootUp[2] < globalTime){
        bootUp.shift();
        bootUp.shift();
        bootUp.shift();
    }
    ctx.fillText(bootUp[0], xx, yy);
    ctx.save(); // need the normal non mirror transform for the noise FX
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
    for(var y = -em/1.2|0; y < em/2; y += 1){
        if((yy+y) % 3 === 0){
            ctx.clearRect(0,yy+y,size,1);  // give scan line look
            
        }else{
            if(Math.random() < 0.1){ // only on 10% of lines.
                ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,yy + y, size, 2,randG(-em4 * 4,em4 * 4,32),yy + y, size, 2);
            }
        }
    }
    ctx.fillRect(0,((globalTime / 4000) * hSize)%hSize,size,2);
    
    ctx.filter = `blur(${randG(em4/2,em4,2)|0}px)`;
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0);
    ctx.restore();
}
const screenFlashes = [0,500,3,1000,200,2,4000,100,3,6000,100,1,7500,50,1,7800,50,1, 9000];

var screenFlashStart;
var screenFlashLen;
var screenFlashDone = true;
var screenFlashLayers = 1;
function screenFlash(ctx,start,length,layers){
    if(start){
        screenFlashStart = globalTime;
        screenFlashLen = length;
        screenFlashDone = false;
        screenFlashLayers = layers;
    }
    var normTime = (globalTime - screenFlashStart) / screenFlashLen;
    if(normTime >= 1){
        screenFlashDone = true;
        normTime = 1;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < screenFlashLayers; i++){
        var tx = randG(-em4 * 4, em4 * 4, 64);  // G for kind of a bit like gausian. Last num controls distrubution
        var ty = randG(-em4 * 4, em4 * 4, 64);
        ctx.globalAlpha = (1-normTime) * Math.random();
        ctx.fillStyle = `hsl(${randG(160,250,32)|0},100%,50%)`;
        ctx.fillRect(tx,ty,size,hSize);
    }
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

function randomBlur(ctx) {
    ctx.save(); // need the normal non mirror transform for the noise FX    
    ctx.filter = `blur(${randG(em4/2,em4,2)|0}px)`;
    ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0);
    ctx.restore();
}

function ready(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
    ctx.font = em + "px monospace";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "center";
    ctx.fillText("Holographic",hSize,em);
    ctx.font = em/2 + "px monospace";
    ctx.fillText("display ready.",hSize,em * 2);
    // draw edges
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0F0";
    ctx.lineWidth = em4;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(size,0);
    ctx.lineTo(hSize + deadZone, hSize - deadZone);
    ctx.lineTo(hSize - deadZone, hSize - deadZone);    
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
function renderContent(ctx){
    // all rendering is mirrored, but the transform takes care of that for you
    // just render as normal. Remember you can only see the
    // triangular area with the wide part at the top
    // and narrow at the bottom.
    
    // Anything below hSize - deadZone will also not appear
    if(globalTime < 8000){
        noisyText(ctx);
        randomBlur(ctx);
    }else{
        ready(ctx);
    }
    randomBlur(ctx);
    

}
```

*A quick side note. I feel your question meets the SO requirements and is not off topic, nor are you asking for someone to write the code. You have shown that you have put some effort into research. This question will be of interest to others. I hope this answer helps, good luck in your project and welcome to SO.*

Comment: thank you a lot! i solved the problem by coding it with Box2d.js, drawing everything four times with a different rotation each time. I'll try your solution too! also thank you for the kind words, i appreciate it.

Comment: @Blindman67: thank you for sharing this snippet, your answer is a mind enjoyment.